# UIPrerenderedIcon required for iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

Setting `UIPrerenderedIcon` is slightly different for iOS 5. Will that also support iOS4, or do I also have to set it the iOS 4 way?

Answer (score 0):

For redundancy's sake I would make sure to set it up for iOS 4 and iOS 5. But you can also test what works yourself if you have a device running iOS 4.